# Call 2 different custom UITableViewCells into UITableViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I've been scouring the web trying to figure this out but can't find a clear answer. Here's what's going on:

I've created a `UITableViewController` called `MainTableViewController` and I have two custom cells that live in that: "FirstCell" and "SecondCell". They both use that naming convention as their reuse identifiers. I've also created cell class files for each: "FirstTableViewCell" and "SecondTableViewCell" that I've assigned each cell accordingly. I've also created `IBOutlets` for all the objects in the cells within each `UITableViewCell` class file.

So in `MainTableViewController` I have no problem getting "FirstCell" loaded. I'm doing that like so:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("FirstCell") as! FirstTableViewCell

    cell.friendfirstnameLabel.text = "Michael"
    cell.friendImageView.image = UIImage(named: "mikepic")

    return cell
}
```

How do I now call "SecondCell"? I know I will need to change my return to 2. But then how do I change the `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` and `cellForRowAtIndexPath` code to make both my cells work?  "Second Cell" has a radically different layout with different objects defined.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return yourArrayCount
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

   if indexPath.row % 2 == 0 { 
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("FirstCell") as! FirstTableViewCell

    cell.friendfirstnameLabel.text = "Michael"
    cell.friendImageView.image = UIImage(named: "mikepic")

    return cell
  } else {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("SecondCell") as! SecondTableViewCell

    cell.friendfirstnameLabel.text = "Michael"
    cell.friendImageView.image = UIImage(named: "mikepic")

    return cell
  }
}
```

Comment: When i try this I enter 2 for "yourArrayCount", but then on the "if indexpath % 2 == 0 {" line i get an error "use of unresolved identifier 'indexpath'"

Comment: just make 'indexpath' to 'indexPath'

Comment: That worked! Thanks Rajatp and @Chonch . However, now when i run it, i only see "FirstCell" in the table. "SecondCell" isn't being loaded below it...

Comment: do you see only one cell or two times the first cell

Comment: I only see one cell - "FirstCell" being displayed once.

Comment: Now you have to debug this. Place the breakpoints in your code to check which code is running and which is not.

Comment: Actually, I just noticed it does load. But for some reason it's underneath the "FirstCell", it only becomes viewable if i pull up on the first cell in the simulator, then it stacks on top of it...i have no idea why this is happening...grrr

Comment: height of both the cell are same or diffrent

Comment: different. In viewDidLoad i'm using tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension. But even when i take that out it does the same thing...

Comment: It has something to do with our autolayout.

Comment: I just deleted all constraints in both cells to see what would happen, and it still does it...lol

Comment: try to use heightForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: You barely know iOS programming. Better go for tutorials.

Comment: Hello @CHM, will you please edit your question and add the screenshots of your tableviewcell design.

Comment: I think he was maybe telling me to go for tutorials. But I think my auto layout constraints are spot on actually. The fact i deleted all constraints and then ran it and had the same problem rules out autolayout as a problem.

Comment: how would i implement the heightForRowAtIndexPath? You've been very helpful @Rajatp and i appreciate all the help you're sending my way. You definitely got me through my first hurdle.

Comment: In my opinion now you try for yourself, try to debug the problem. We will close this question.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to deque your second cell with the reuse identifier assigned. This is completely on your requirements when you want to use first and when second.

Comment: I want to use both at the same time in the tableViewController stacked on top of one another.

Answer (score 0):

You should simply change the parameter value you send to `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` based on `[indexPath row]`. If it's 0, use `"firstCell"` and if it's 1, use `"secondCell"` and create a cell for the matching object type.

Comment: :-) Have you tried @Rajatp solution? It's pretty much the same thing I was referring to. The idea is that you use the deque method to indicate to the operating system which type of cell you would like to use for the current row. If you indicate "firstCell" it will give you a cell from that type (if it has one, otherwise, you'll create a new one), and if you indicate "secondCell" it will give you a matching cell. Does that make it a bit clearer?

Comment: I think i've tried what you're suggesting, and I can't get it to work. I tried: let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("FirstCell") as! FirstTableViewCell
    cell.friendfirstnameLabel.text = "Michael"
    cell.friendImageView.image = UIImage(named: "mikepic")     let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("SecondCell") as! SecondTableViewCell
    cell.businessImageView.image = UIImage(named: "bizpic")

Comment: It's not indented in the comment, but it seems like you're missing an if statement to decide whether to use "firstCell" or "secondCell" for this row. You can't use both, you're only working on a single cell whenever this method gets called.

Comment: I tried @rajatp solution and i enter 2 for "yourArrayCount", but then on the "if indexpath % 2 == 0 {" line i get an error "use of unresolved identifier 'indexpath'"

Comment: Should be "indexPath" (with a capital P)

Comment: @Chonch yup 'P' is the culprit :).

Comment: @Rajatp why did you delete your answer??

Answer (score 0):

here i see you have  static text  to show in the  cell view. Usually we have NSArray of data  to populate the data in tableview and we define the count in umberOfRowsInSection method
so it will be very easy if you know what data you want  to display in which  cell like  that  you can easily  use If statement for selecting  your desire table cellview

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
return arrayCount
}
```

after checking  count  you can do this by if statement

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
NSUInteger row = [indexPath row]; 

if [yourArray objectAtIndex:row] =="Michael" { 
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("FirstCell") as! FirstTableViewCell

cell.friendfirstnameLabel.text = "Michael"
cell.friendImageView.image = UIImage(named: "mikepic")

return cell
} else {
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("SecondCell") as! SecondTableViewCell

cell.friendfirstnameLabel.text = “Unknown"
cell.friendImageView.image = UIImage(named: "mikepic")

 return cell
 }
}
```